# Quotient of scalar products

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given fixed $x$ and $y$. Is it possible to extend the quotient $\frac{<x,1>}{<y,1>}?=?\frac{<x,a>}{<y,a>}$ where $<,>$ is the common dot product,$a$ is any vector and $1$ is a vector of $1's$.

Where extend means $\frac{a}{b}\cdot 1=\frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{c}{c}=\frac{ac}{bc} $

Comment: What does it mean to extend a quotient?

Comment: It's easy enough to make up some examples where your two fractions aren't equal. I think you get equality only when $a$ is a scalar multiple of a vector with all $1$s. But as @lulu pointed out, I'm also not sure what it means to extend a quotient.

Comment: @lulu $\frac{a}{b}\cdot 1=\frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{c}{c} $

Comment: What on earth does that mean?

Comment: I don't think  you have thought through your question.  Take a look at the usual inner product on $\mathbb R^2$.  In that context you should be able to write out whatever you meant explicitly.

Comment: $\frac{a}{b}\cdot 1=\frac{ac}{bc}$? is that more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $1 = (1, \ldots, 1)$ it's **not** true that $\frac{\langle x, 1 \rangle}{\langle y, 1 \rangle} = \frac{\langle x, a \rangle}{\langle y, a \rangle}$ for any vector $a$. For example, take $x=(1, -1),\ y=(1,1),\ a=(1,0).$ Then,
$$\begin{align}
\langle x, 1 \rangle &= 1\cdot 1 + (-1)\cdot 1 = 0, \\
\langle y, 1 \rangle &= 1\cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 1 = 2, \\
\langle x, a \rangle &= 1\cdot 1 + (-1) \cdot 0 = 1, \\
\langle y, a \rangle &= 1\cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 0 = 1, \\
\end{align}$$
so
$\frac{\langle x, 1 \rangle}{\langle y, 1 \rangle} = \frac{0}{2} = 0$
but
$\frac{\langle x, a \rangle}{\langle y, a \rangle} = \frac{1}{1} = 1.$